# AssertionError: expected 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to include 'text/html'

Tags: node.js, express, postman, mern

Getting this error in Postman when trying: http://locahost:3000/user .
AssertionError: expected 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to include 'text/html
But status code is 200.

```
app.get('/user', (req, res)=>{
   
    User.find().then(users=>res.status(200).json(users))
    .catch(err=>{
        console.error(`Error in Database ${err}`);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error'});
    })
});



res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

I tried using this piece of code just above `User.find()`.//Rest of my code......
But the problem remains the same.